# Complex MySql query help needed

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find data that may be missing from my database.  I have three tables that are part of this.  The first is an event table, the second is a sub-event table, and the third is a individual persons' data from a sub-event for a portion of the sub-events.

What I would like to do is:
For each event find the sub-events associated with it, if the sub-event has the field tfile set then ignore it, if it doesn't then look at the individual persons' data.  If there are 0 matching records in that then output to the list.

Here is what I think would work, but isn't right:

```
select event.*, subevent.* from event.id
join subevent on event.id = subevent.eid
join pdata on subevent.subid = pdata.subid
where subevent.textfile = ''
and Count(pdata.subid) = 0;
```

Edit: Added code from user, uses real table names:

```
SELECT tb_event.*, cr_event.* 
FROM tb_event
INNER JOIN cr_event ON tb_event.id = cr_event.eid
INNER JOIN searchable_data ON cr_event.id = searchable_data.race_id
WHERE cr_event.tfile = ''
GROUP BY cr_event.id
HAVING Count(searchable_data.race_id) = 0
```

Additional information, I believe the issue is around how many items are in the searchable_data.  It doesn't seem to find the ones with zero (that I know exist).

as per suggestion of Nick I added columns to the group by

```
SELECT tb_event.*, cr_event.id 
FROM tb_event
INNER JOIN cr_event ON tb_event.id = cr_event.eid
INNER JOIN searchable_data ON cr_event.id = searchable_data.race_id
WHERE cr_event.tfile = ''
GROUP BY tb_event.id, tb_event.ename, tb_event.ecity, tb_event.eplace, tb_event.elocation, tb_event.zip, tb_event.day, tb_event.year, tb_event.etime, tb_event.logo, tb_event.remail, tb_event.descr, tb_event.link, tb_event.reg, tb_event.rname, tb_event.created_by, cr_event.id
HAVING Count(searchable_data.race_id) = 0
```

[Link to Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4nij.jpg)

I have tried for about an hour to get this one query working.  Anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: Thanks Wesley, I was trying to do the same thing and hadn't figured it out.

Comment: What was the output of this most recent query?

Comment: I am not sure if this would help or not, however the searchable_data table wouldn't have any rows in it for the items I am looking for.

Comment: Could you post some sample data that I can use in testing?

Comment: I also added a null check to my query below in case tfile is null instead of just being an empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to count something that - well, doesn't quite exist because of your INNER JOIN.

You'll need to keep the t/c combinations that doesn't have any matching data in s. See below query to list all t/c id pairs (unique due to GROUP BY) that doesn't have any data in s.

```
SELECT t.id, c.id 
FROM tb_event t
INNER JOIN cr_event c ON t.id = c.eid
LEFT OUTER JOIN searchable_data s ON c.id = s.race_id

WHERE c.tfile = ''
AND s.race_id IS NULL -- This is what you need to check for
GROUP BY t.id, c.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
SELECT tb_event.*, cr_event.id 
FROM tb_event
INNER JOIN cr_event ON tb_event.id = cr_event.eid
INNER JOIN searchable_data ON cr_event.id = searchable_data.race_id
WHERE cr_event.tfile = '' OR cr_event.tfile IS NULL
GROUP BY tb_event.id, tb_event.ename, tb_event.ecity, tb_event.eplace, tb_event.elocation, tb_event.zip, tb_event.day, tb_event.year, tb_event.etime, tb_event.logo, tb_event.remail, tb_event.descr, tb_event.link, tb_event.reg, tb_event.rname, tb_event.created_by, cr_event.id
HAVING Count(searchable_data.race_id) = 0
```

Report errors/incorrect data it returns.

Comment: Nick,  See above mysql I ran, returned 0 rows.

Comment: In order for the HAVING statement to work, you'll need to put every field in the GROUP BY that are included in your select statement. Since you're doing tb_event.* and cr_event.*, you'll need to list every column for both of these tables in the GROUP BY. It may help if you can post the columns of all of the respective tables.

Comment: Nick I added a link to the table structure for the three tables.  Hope this helps.  Thanks for helping in general as well.